# JSON string serialization (Newtonsoft.JSON)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I get a JSON string as HTTP response. This string looks like:

```
response: {
    count: 524,
    items: [{
        id: 318936948,
        owner_id: 34,
        artist: 'The Smiths',
        title: 'How Soon Is Now',
        duration: 233,
        url: 'link',
        genre_id: 9
    }, {
        id: 312975563,
        owner_id: 34,
        artist: 'Thom Yorke',
        title: 'Guess Again!',
        duration: 263,
        url: 'link',
        genre_id: 22
    }]
}
```

I have Newtonsoft.Json library, and classes Response and Item:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int count { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
class Item
{
    public string aid { get; set; }
    public string owner_id { get; set; }
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int lyrics_id { get; set; }
    public int album_id { get; set; }
    public int genre_id { get; set; }
}
```

And I deserialize it like that:

```
Response r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(line);
```

It doesn't work, "r" remains null. Where am I wrong and why? It's compiling, it leaves no exceptions.

Comment: I get a bunch of errors when I paste your Json into http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, such as "Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 2]".

Comment: Json seems to be wrong. check here http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Also, it looks like `response` is a field/property in some containing structure, but you don't show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. Your JSON string is missing outer parenthesis.  It should look like

   ```
   { response: {
       count: 524,
       items: [{
           id: 318936948,
           owner_id: 34,
           artist: 'The Smiths',
           title: 'How Soon Is Now',
           duration: 233,
           url: 'link',
           genre_id: 9
       }, {
           id: 312975563,
           owner_id: 34,
           artist: 'Thom Yorke',
           title: 'Guess Again!',
           duration: 263,
           url: 'link',
           genre_id: 22
       }]
   }}
   ```
2. You are trying to deserialize the `Response` class but there is no field `response` in this class, it's evidently a field in some containing class.  So, you need to extract out the actual `Response`.
3. Your property `aid` in `Item` needs to be named `id`.

So, the following seems to work:

```
            // Fix missing outer parenthesis
            var fixedLine = "{" + line + "}";

            // Parse into a JObject
            var mapping = JObject.Parse(fixedLine);

            // Extract the "response" and deserialize it.
            Response r = mapping["response"].ToObject<Response>();

            Debug.WriteLine(r.count);
            foreach (var item in r.items)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("  " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
            }
```

This produces the debug output

```
524
  {"id":"318936948","owner_id":"34","artist":"The Smiths","title":"How Soon Is Now","duration":"233","url":"link","lyrics_id":0,"album_id":0,"genre_id":9}
  {"id":"312975563","owner_id":"34","artist":"Thom Yorke","title":"Guess Again!","duration":"263","url":"link","lyrics_id":0,"album_id":0,"genre_id":22}
```

And shows the data was deserialized successfully.

Comment: It works that way, i havent fixed line, but with JObject it deserializes. But I still don't understand, what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as-is for me. Does the JSON string you receive contain the `response:` bit at the beginning? If so, you need to strip that out (remove everything in the string prior to the first `{` character), then it should work for you.